# Converting String list to pure list in Python

Tags: python, bash, list

I have a string type list from bash which looks like this:

> inp = "["one","two","three","four","five"]"

The input is coming from bash script.
In my python script I would like to convert this to normal python list in this format:

> ["one","two","three","four","five"]

where all elements would be string, but the whole thin is represented as list.

I tried: list(inp)
it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code,

```
import ast
inp = '["one","two","three","four","five"]'
ast.literal_eval(inp) # will prints ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> inp = '["one","two","three","four","five"]'
>>> converted_inp = ast.literal_eval(inp)
>>> type(converted_inp)
<class 'list'>
>>> print(converted_inp)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Notice that your original input string is not a valid python string, since it ends after `"["`.

```
>>> inp = "["one","two","three","four","five"]"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `re.sub()` and `str.split()` functions:

```
import re
inp = '["one","two","three","four","five"]'
l = re.sub(r'["\]\[]', '', inp).split(',')

print(l)
```

The output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use replace and split as the following:

```
>>> inp
"['one','two','three','four','five']"

>>> inp.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','').split(',')
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```